# How to make a class itself generic?

Tags: dart

```
class Node {
  List<Node> children;
}

class TreeNode extends Node {
  @Override
  List<TreeNode> children; // ERROR: could not override writer method.
}
```

Is there a way to make generic so that:

```
treeNode.children is List<TreeNode>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstract `Node` class with a generic type parameter `T`. This `T` will represent the type of children nodes:

```dart
abstract class Node<T extends Node<T>> {
  List<T> children;
}
```

`T extends Node<T>` means that `T` should be a subtype of `Node<T>` itself.

Now, let's create a `TreeNode` class that extends `Node` and specifies `TreeNode` as the type parameter:

```dart
class TreeNode extends Node<TreeNode> {
  @override
  List<TreeNode> children;
}
```

In this case, `TreeNode` extends `Node<TreeNode>`, so the `children` list will be of type `List<TreeNode>`, as you wanted. This way, you're not overriding the `children` property with a different type, but specializing the `Node` class for `TreeNode` instances.

Comment: one minor issue: T node = this; need a cast. T node = this as T.